# $\phi_1∧ ... ∧\phi_n = (det A) dx_1 ∧ ... dx_n$

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, tensors, exterior-algebra

For $i=1,...,n$, we consider the 1-tensors on $\mathbb{R}^n$ given by:
$$\phi_i:=\sum_{k=1}^{n} \alpha_{ik}\mathrm{d}x_k \in \Lambda^1((\mathbb{R}^n)^*),$$ where $ A=(\alpha_{ik})_{1 \le i, k\le n} \in \mathrm{Mat}(n; \mathbb{R})$.
Show that
$$\phi_1∧ ... ∧\phi_n = (\det A) \mathrm{d}x_1 \land \cdots \land \mathrm{d}x_n.$$
What I thought:
$$\phi_1 \land \cdots \land \phi_n=\alpha_1\mathrm{d}x_1 \land \cdots \land \alpha_n\mathrm{d}x_n= \left(\sum_{k=1}^{n} \alpha_{ik}\right) \mathrm{d}x_1\land \cdots \land\mathrm{d}x_n.$$
I don't know how to continue and I don't know if it really makes sense...

Comment: What you wrote down is not correct. You assumed that $\phi_i=\alpha_idx_i$ which isn't true at all, each $\phi_i$ is a linear combination of the $dx_j$. Instead, write down the sum for each term and use the distributive, linear and alternating properties of the wedge product to arrive at an expression that is known as the "Leibniz formula for determinants".

Comment: @QuaereVerum I understand, but I still can't get from one side of the problem to the other...

Comment: Neither "algebraic geometry" nor "outer product" are appropriate tags here.  This is fundamentally a question about linear algebra --- I would replace those two with that.

Comment: Are you sure the $\mathrm d$ should be in your formula for the $\phi_i$?

Comment: @J.G. yes I am sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think in a simple example: In $\mathbb R^2$, if $\phi_1 := a_{11}dx_1 + a_{12}dx_2$ and  $\phi_2 := a_{21}dx_1 + a_{22}dx_2$, then using the bilinearity of $\wedge$ together with the fact that $dx_i \wedge dx_j = -dx_j \wedge dx_i$ for any $i$ and $j$ (in particular, $dx_i \wedge dx_j = 0$ when $i=j$) we have
\begin{align}
\phi_1 \wedge \phi_2 &= (a_{11}dx_1 + a_{12}dx_2) \wedge (a_{21}dx_1 + a_{22}dx_2) \\
&= a_{11}a_{21}dx_1 \wedge dx_1 + a_{11}a_{22}dx_1 \wedge dx_2 \\ & \qquad \qquad + a_{12}a_{21}dx_2 \wedge dx_1 + a_{12}a_{22}dx_2 \wedge dx_2 \\
&= a_{11}a_{22}dx_1 \wedge dx_2 + a_{12}a_{21}(-dx_1 \wedge dx_2) \\
&= (a_{11}a_{22} - a_{12}a_{21})dx_1 \wedge dx_2 \\
&= \det\! \begin{pmatrix} a_{11}&a_{12} \\ a_{21}&a_{22} \end{pmatrix} dx_1 \wedge dx_2.
\end{align}